# MDX Using Member_Key

Tags: mdx, pentaho

I'm trying to write a query which uses order in the Pentaho Schema Workbench program.

A simple query I pulled from Saiku analysis's GUI runs without issue. 
[image]

Trying to add in an order yields the message **"No function matches signature '.Member_Key'"**
[image]

How would I got about debugging this? All the examples I see online for ordering data use CurrentMember and Member_Key so I'm a little lost.

Comment: @ConsiderMe are the intrensic properties like MEMBER_KEY supposed to be actual columns in the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this page](http://diethardsteiner.github.io/olap/2015/02/27/Mondrian-MDX-Intrinsic-Member-Properties.html) online which shows how to access intrinsic properties through Mondrian MDX.

Instead of `[DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].CurrentMember.MEMBER_KEY` you write `[DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].CurrentMember.Properties("MEMBER_KEY")`

Answer (score 2):

These are the properties:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145528.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Try `MEMBER_VALUE` instead of the key.

Also try without the underscore as `MEMBERVALUE`

Comment: Thanks for that list of properties.It looks like MEMBER_VALUE doesn't want to go through either. Would you know offhand if Pentaho's Mondrian doesn't support these?